# How to use Google Cloud Dataproc with machine-level parallelism?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, distributed-computing, google-cloud-dataproc

This is the basic outline of the problem I'm trying to solve:

- I have a list of inputs (~500), which each need to be processed independently
- I want to be able to complete these processes with parallelization via a cluster of worker machines (I assume Dataproc is the right tool here)
- Processing each input can take a lot of time, and requires full independent use of the worker machine (multiple TB of disk space, access to all CPU cores)

So far, I've been able to get this to (kind of) work using Spark. I set the following configuration parameters:

`spark.executor.instances` -- to the number of worker machines in my cluster

`spark.executor.cores` -- to the number of cores in each of my worker machines

`spark.task.cpus` -- also to the number of cores in each of my worker machines

I also manually set the Spark dataframe partition size to be 1, so that inputs are fluidly assigned to available worker machines rather than being batched into partitions. This configuration got it down to two simultaneous tasks per worker machine, which isn't ideal but worked okay.

However, I seem to be fighting against Spark at every turn, and it has me wondering if this is even the right technology to be using here. Should I continue trying to achieve this on Spark, and if so, how do I do this? And if Spark is not the right tech here, what is?